# Calling functions in global.asa

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, session-variables, global.asa

I would like to call a function from another file in the `Session_OnStart` part if `global.asa`, so I could declare some `Session("variables")` according to some data.

Is it possible?
How?

**Edit:** I found a workaround, where I have a global functions file that I include everywhere. So I added to the code to this file.
It's not perfect, because even though it's a small piece of code, it still runs every refresh, instead of once at the `Session_OnStart`.

Any other solutions?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code examples of what you have tried?

Comment: I edited the question so now it tells about a workaround that I did.

Comment: Will you please post the code that runs every refresh?

Comment: You can read the file using FSO.

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed not possible to add include files to you global.asa. You could do the following:

Create a 'flag' in the session that says if it's a new session. Fill it in the Session_OnStart (i.e. Session("NewSession") = True) and verify this before executing your global function(s).